# XOR of the value of the same column across different rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, xor

My query should return the list of all inbound and outbound messages of the specific person. I'm working on [Enron Email Dataset in MySQL](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3802/enron-email-dataset-in-mysql), in this DB the same message can't be duplicated with different tags, such as *«to»*, *«cc»*, *«bcc»*, yes this DB is not well ACID-formed.

But I want to eliminate this repeats, e.g. if I got the message with the tag *«to»*, I don't want to see the same message sended to the same person with the tag *«cc»*. The naive approach is to try to use something like ***XOR***, which will exclude all repeats, but how to get it working when I should compare the value of the same column across different rows?

Current result is:
[image: query result set example]
While I expect to see only one of these two rows.

The kind of ERD, the structure of the tables, used in the query:
[image: Enron Email Dataset partly ERD]

The code of the query:

```sql
SELECT
  left(m.messagedt, 10) AS 'date',
  m.messageid           AS 'message id',
  r.reciptype           AS 'type',
  m.subject             AS 'message subject',
  b.body                AS 'message body',
  s.personid            AS 'sender id',
  s.name                AS 'sender',
  s.email               AS 'sender email',
  t.personid            AS 'receiver id',
  t.name                AS 'receiver',
  t.email               AS 'receiver email'

FROM messages AS m
  JOIN bodies AS b
    ON b.messageid = m.messageid
  JOIN recipients AS r
    ON r.messageid = m.messageid
  JOIN people AS t
    ON t.personid = r.personid
  JOIN people AS s
    ON s.personid = m.senderid

WHERE (
  s.email = 'lisa.jones@enron.com'
  XOR
  t.email = 'lisa.jones@enron.com'
)

ORDER BY m.messagedt,
         m.messageid;
```

I'll stress, the aim of the query is to get the list of all messages, that have been sent to the specific user or from the specific user. This is why I use the ***JOIN*** twice: one for the inbound messages (*people as t*) and one for the outbound (*people as s*). Feel free to re-organize the query.

Comment: Please show us the table structure (CREATE TABLE queries)

Comment: can you provide sample data and expected result here or at sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: The complete sample data: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rjurney_public_web/images/enron.mysql.5.5.20.sql.gz it is a MySQL-dump of the database, since you uploaded it to MySQL you can execute my query or write your-own query. The expected result is when I see the same message, like in the first screenshot, with absolutely the same values except the value of «r.reciptype», which may vary (to/cc/bcc) to show only one (first string) of these «same» strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XOR eliminames emails from a sender to himself. Is this what you really need?

Think you need

```sql
group by m.messageid, t.email
```

instead of XOR